# is it same thing to say that a group has a subgroup of order x or it has an element of order x

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My take on this is that a subgroup may not be generated by a single element in which case an element of order x is different than subgroup of order x.Please help me understand this better.

Comment: Your impression is correct. For an example consider the group $S_4$. It has a subgroup of order six, but no elements of order six. Or the group $\Bbb{Z}_{24}^*$, a group of order eight. It has subgroups of order four but all the non-identity elements have order two. In both cases those subgroups cannot be generated by a single element.

Comment: If you add the word "cyclic" (as in, a group has a *cyclic* subgroup of order x if and only if it has an element of order x) then the statement becomes true. The subgroup generated by an element has the same order as the element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct that these are not equivalent. However, if a group has an element of order $x$, then it has a subgroup of order $x$ (why?)

To see that the reverse is false, consider the group $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, where $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is the cyclic group of order $2$. This group has a subgroup of order $4$ (itself), but has no element of order $4$ (every non-identity element has order $2$).